# Update data value while rendering in Vue JS for accessibility purposes

Tags: vuejs2, accessibility, v-for, tabindex

I'm learning VueJS and I'm having this error while trying to make a page accessible through tabs (jumping from one Div to another) using the "tabIndex" property. The problem I'm having right now is that all the divs on the page are conditioned, sometimes they all can be there but sometimes only one, and so on... they come from an array of hashes, something like this:

```
    (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name_old: "The name before",  name_new: "new name", created: "2022-04-19 17:18:36", type: 1, observation: "ok"}
1: {description_old: "old description", description_new: "new description", created: "2022-04-19 16:30:00", type: 1, observation: null}
2: {name_old: null, name_new: "The name before", description_old: null, description_new: "old description", impact_old: null, …}
```

Basically, it's my way to save changes of a table from my database having the old and the new values...

So, I'm rendering this data with a v-for, something like this:

```
  <v-timeline-item
    v-for="n in items"
    :key="n.item_id"
    small
    fill-dot
  >
```

And I check if the element is null or not, so I can render it

```
<div v-if="n.description_new && n.description_old" :tabIndex="(tab_idx+= 1)">
```

The problem is, without the "tabIndex" property, basically, I cant navigate the page using the tab key.

I have on my "Data" part of the code a variable named "tab_idx" that I use for counting the current tabIndex value. (Starting it at 9 because I have 8 static values before the v-for)

```
  data: () => ({
   tab_idx: 9
  }),
```

But I get this error:

> You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Is there any workaround to solve this?

Ps: I tried using a prop as the tab_idx value but I got this error.

> Unexpected mutation of "tabIndex" prop                                                                                                                                                                                                                vue/no-mutating-props

Thanks!

Comment: A reproducible example would increase the chance to get a complete answer. However, it looks like you bind (`:tabIndex="(tab_idx+= 1)"`) and modify (`tab_idx+= 1`) your variable `tab_idx` in the same expression. Try to load the index without binding it, or calculate the index using the for index of the for-loop

Comment: Just a note, it looks like you're incrementing the `tabindex` attribute with each new `<div>` that you insert on your page. You only need `tabindex="0"` in order to make the `<div>` elements keyboard accessible; you don't have to specify the tab order (in fact, it's not recommended). But I agree with @Uchendu that you should try and post a reproducible example or a link to your app so we can test it on our own machines.

Comment: Hey, I did a workaround adding an index to each data value in the array so I could know if the new name was the tabidx 9 and the old name was the tabidx 10, i know is not the best but worked for me. Thanks though